# Bootstrap and bootbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

Im trying to create bootbox dialog, that has three buttons, which can be switched depending on  certain permissions.

I can create the dialog with all three buttons, but im not sure how to dynamically, disable buttons in my javascript. I can find out how to disable a peice fo html using the following:

```
<c:when test="${ loginDetails.canRender }">
```

Is it possible to disble my buttons on my bootbox dialog, in my javascript:

```
bootbox.dialog("Do you want to continue ?", [{
    "label" : "render",
    "class" : "btn-success",
    "callback": function() {                        

    }
}, {
    "label" : "overrride",
    "class" : "btn-primary",
    "callback": function() {
        // do nothing
    }
}]);
```

so if i have permission to render, i want the render button enabled.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar Problem and I found a way to access the Buttons via JQuery.

overrideCreate your bootbox dialog with:

```
bootbox.dialog({
      message: "Do you want to continue ?",
      buttons: {
        render: {
                 label: "render",
                 className: "btn-success",
                 callback: function() {}
                 },
                overrride: {
                  label: "override",
                  className: "btn-primary",
                  callback: function() {}
                 }
      }
    });
```

Creating the Buttons like that allows you to access the via jQuery Selector e.g.

```
$('button[data-bb-handler=render]')
```

(replace "render" with your label)

Now you can hide/show your render button with:

```
$('button[data-bb-handler=render]').show();
$('button[data-bb-handler=render]').hide();
```

Comment: Add some explenation why he should do that.